# Pipe doesn't update the template when remove a item from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I was not able to refresh the template after I have removed the item from `pages` array due to `normalizeUri` pipe. Same code is working fine without `normalizeUri` pipe. Can you tell me what was the issue of pipe implementation? i.e. Why template doesn't update if there is pipe.

*.html*

```
  <ion-slides pager (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
    <ion-slide *ngFor='let page of pages | normalizeUri'>
      <img [src]='page' />
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

*.ts*

```
  async removePage() {
    try {

      await SbSdk.removePage({ page: this.selectedPage });
      let pageIndexToRemove = null;
      this.pages.forEach((p, index) => {
        if (this.selectedPage.pageId === p.pageId) {
          pageIndexToRemove = index;
        }
      });

      this.pages.splice(pageIndexToRemove, 1);
      this.selectedPage = null;

      if (this.pages.length == 0) {//no pages
        this.goToScan();
        return;
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.goToSlide(this.pages.length - 1);
        }, 500);
      }
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageHandlingProvider } from '../../providers/image-handling/image-handling';
import { Page } from 'cordova-plugin-scanbot-sdk';

@Pipe({
  name: 'normalizeUri',
})
export class NormalizeUriPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private imageHandlingProvider: ImageHandlingProvider) { }
  transform(pages: Page[]): string[] {
    return pages.map((p) => {
      return this.imageHandlingProvider.normalizeImageFileUri(p.documentPreviewImageFileUri || p.originalPreviewImageFileUri);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: If there is no necessity of keeping the same reference, then you can try `this.pages = this.pages.filter(p => this.selectedPage.pageId !== p.pageId)` instead of finding the index and splicing. This way you will be able to work with pure pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `impure` pipe for that

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'normalizeUri',
  pure: false
})
```

https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068

But the impure pipe is not reliable to use.

Comment: Perfect. For my use case, performance is not an issue since that page won't exist for more than a few seconds. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Sampath. Glad to help you.!

Answer (score 0):

You've created what is considered a Pure pipe. When the type is not specified, that is the default. Pure pipes are only executed "when it detects a **pure change** to the input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference (Date, Array, Function, Object)." ([Angular Manual](https://angular.io/guide/pipes))

To turn your pipe impure, add the false flag to the pipe decorator:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'normalizeUri',
  pure: false
})
```

Because Pure pipes get executed a lot, they are in general discouraged. *An impure pipe is called often, as often as every keystroke or mouse-move.* (Angular Manual)

Instead, consider normalising your URIs before assigning them to an object that will be rendered in a template.